# What is the difference between *.XACRO and *.URDF.XACRO files?

Tags: urdf, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is this difference significant?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/70837/what-is-the-difference-between-*.xacro-and-*.urdf.xacro-files?/) by [nemesis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4134/nemesis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 237 on 2013-08-02

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AFAIK, no.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2013-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3